# SFTP Spring Integrations rm command

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am wondering if someone can assist, I know I am doing this wrong and I'm tearing my hair out.  My goal is to delete any files with a .txt extension in a remote directory using Spring Integrations SFTP in a Spring Batch job.  It is my understanding that I do not have to ls remote files to remove them and can just issue an rm command on *.txt for a given directory however I may be incorrect?

I have the following SFTP configuration

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${port}" />
    <property name="user" value="${user}" />        
    <property name="privateKey" value="file:${privateKey}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="rmChannel"/>

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="rmChannel"
        remote-file-separator="/"
        command="rm"
        expression="headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile']" />

<bean id="cleanRemoteDirectoryTasklet" class="com.example.batch.job.integration.SFTPRmTasklet" scope="step">
    <property name="channel" ref="rmChannel" />
    <property name="filePatternToDelete" value="*.txt" />
    <property name="targetDirectory" value="${remoteDirectory}"/> // edit removed 'file:' notation
</bean>
```

I believe I am OK to this point an my problem is executing this flow in the Java implementation in SFTPRmTasklet, I'm not sure how to construct the message to initiate the sftp remove.  Currently I have something like this simply to kick it off I know that my payload is wrong.

```
Message<String> rmRequest = MessageBuilder.withPayload("/my/target/dir")
                .setHeader("file_remoteDirectory", targetDirectory)
                .setHeader("file_remoteFile", filePatternToDelete)
                .build();

channel.send(rmRequest)
```

ultimately this yields an exception

```
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to remove file: 2: No such file
```

**UPDATE 1**

So I decided to target just one remote file and changed filePatternToDelete to test.txt.  After a bit of debugging I realised that `AbstractRemoteFileOutBoundGateway` was evaluating my remoteFilePath to /my/target/dirtest.txt and remote filename to dirtest.txt, which is obviously not what I wanted so I added a trailing to / to the target directory in my properties file and this sorted out this error great!

I can now delete the file from the remote server as I wished to do however I received an error around no reply-channel so I have added the following channel

```
<int:channel id="end"/>
```

and modified my outbound gateway

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="rmChannel"
        reply-channel="end"
        remote-file-separator="/"
        command="rm"
        expression="headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile']" />
```

and now get an error around no subscribers for this channel. Progress at least and in case you hadn't guessed I'm pretty new to Spring!

Comment: Paste the entire log. Plus, do you have permissions to delete files as an user? What do the server logs on the machine on which you are trying to delete files indicate.

Comment: I am curious as to why you have a `file:` prefix in the `targetDirectory` property; can you show how that setter is defined and where you get the `targetDirectory` value for the header.

Comment: Hi Gary, good spot I believe the 'file:' notation was in error, I am working on some existing unfinished code.  The values are in a properties file that is specified in the JAVA_OPTS and then picked up the application e.g.

-DpropertiesFile=/my/dir/batch.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not interested in the result of the `rm`, set the `reply-channel` to `nullChannel`.

It's like `/dev/null` on unix.